# How to create and use custom command line parameters in locust

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I was able to add custom command line parameters to locust script like below -
'''
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
parser.add_argument(
'--custom-argument',
help="It's working"
)
'''

But I am unable to use the custom argument anywhere else in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access command line options via the `environment`. You can create another function tagged with the `init` listener to access it and save it into some other variable you can use anywhere. This was adapted from [the example](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/add_command_line_argument.py):

```
custom = None
@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    global custom
    custom = environment.parsed_options.custom_argument
```