# Locust - Accessing CLI args in LoadTestShape's __init__

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am performing load test using `locust` and have implemented RPS based load generation using a custom class from `LoadTestShape`.
This custom class holds methods for different load shapes like `_tick_step_increase`, `_tick_rps_based`, etc.:

```py
class CustomLoadShape:
    # factory class that holds different shape methods #

    def __init__(self, step_interval=5, max_rps=500):
        self.step_interval = step_interval
        self.max_rps = max_rps

    def _tick_step_increase(self):
        # use self.interval here #
        pass

    def _tick_square_wave(self):
        # use self.max_rps here #
        pass

class MyCustomLoadShape(LoadTestShape, CustomLoadShape):
    # this class is present in locustfile #

    def __init__(self):
        CustomLoadShape.__init__()
        setattr(self, "tick", self._tick_rps_based)     # this is how i make sure the `tick` method is defined
```

I am accepting some cli args, say, `max-rps` and wish to pass them to `MyCustomLoadShape` (eventually to `CustomLoadShape`).

I know that in the task functions, we can access cli args as `self.environment.parsed_options.max_rps`.

Intuitively, I tried to do the same in `__init__` but it does not have `self.environment` and `self.runner` is `None` (somehow it appears as an object in the `tick` method).

Although we can access cli args in the `tick` method using `self.runner.environment.parsed_options.max_rps`, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in `__init__` so that we could play around with attributes in a more OOP way.

Answer (score 1):

I answered another similar question recently:

[How to create and use custom command line parameters in locust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071273/how-to-create-and-use-custom-command-line-parameters-in-locust)

If you can't access the environment inside the LoadShape class, I'd recommend just setting a global variable with another function that runs on `init` like so:

```
max_rps = None
step_interval = None
@events.init.add_listener
def set_max_rps(environment, **kw):
    global max_rps
    max_rps = environment.parsed_options.max_rps
    global step_interval = None
    step_interval = None
```

Then you could access it from your other classes:

```
class CustomLoadShape:
    # factory class that holds different shape methods #

    def _tick_step_increase(self):
        # use interval here #
        step_interval
        pass

    def _tick_square_wave(self):
        # use max rps here #
        max_rps
        pass
```

Comment: This is one way, although i normally tend to avoid using globals.. still trying to figure out how to get `self.runner` not None in `__init__`..

Comment: i found that we could load the parser in `MyCustomLoadShape` during `__init__` as `locust.argument_parser.parse_options()` and then access the cli args. the only downside is that the function to parse cli args will be called twice - one by locust and then by this call